# onClick not responding i.e, not running specified function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here in the below code i'm trying to run a function that will change the state of component on click of a button named as people using component infoButton, but the problem is onClick function which was supposed to run on click of the button is not running and i can't understand why?
IMPORTANT part of code is marked inside star(**** ****)

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/header';
import InfoButton from './components/infoButtons';
import People from './components/people';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      route:'mainPage',
      arrayNames:[],
      peopleClicked:false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/')
    .then(resp=>resp.json())
    .then(result=>{
      this.setState({
        arrayNames:result.results
      })
    })
  }
***** the problem lies here, onclick is not running this function *******
  alteringPeopleClicked=()=>{
    console.log('working alteringPeopleClicked');
    this.setState({
      route:'notMainPage',
      peopleClicked:true
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Header/>
        {******here is your onClick used inside infobutton*******
          this.state.route==='mainPage'?<InfoButton onClick={ this.alteringPeopleClicked } buttonText={'people'}/>
          :<People 
            peopleClicked={this.state.peopleClicked} 
            arrayNames={this.state.arrayNames}/>
        }
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

edit: I'm attaching implementation of infobutton since you asked for it

```
import React from 'react';

const InfoButton=(props)=>{
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <button>{props.buttonText}</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default InfoButton;
```

Comment: We'll need to see the implementation of `InfoButton` since the handler is being passed as a prop to it.

Comment: Try this    <InfoButton onClick={()=>this.alteringPeopleClicked()} buttonText={'people'}/>

Comment: @muddassir that will do nothing different... Declaring a new inline function vs passing its reference directly will have no difference in behavior.

Comment: `alteringPeopleClicked=()=>` try `alteringPeopleClicked(){}` this

Comment: @Brian Thompson - Just a try as you said props might be the problem

Comment: edit the last comment but i think that will not resolve your issue

Comment: @RajeshVerma Now it is valid syntax, but now it would break because `this` will most likely not be defined.

Comment: [link](https://codepen.io/dvbnrg/pen/xdoexB) might help

Comment: @Harsh - Try <button onClick={ this.alteringPeopleClicked }>people</button> and see if this works . This will help you confirm if this is a problem with the InfoButton component

Comment: If I had to take a guess based on common misconceptions, I'd say that `InfoButton` doesn't implement the `onClick` prop. The common misconception is that you may assign an `onClick` handler to any react element and it will fire when that *component* is clicked. But this isn't how it actually works. You may only assign `onClick` to a dom element that will use it (like a `div` or `button`) **or** a react component that will do that for you.

Comment: @BrianThompson you were right, instead of using onClick on infobutton i passed the fn refernce to component and then used onClick in button tag where it worked

Answer (score 0):

Please add onClick to button

```
import React from 'react';

const InfoButton=(props)=>{
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <button onClick={props.onClick}>{props.buttonText}</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default InfoButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

Brian Thompson's comment is wise advice.  Not every react component can take an event handler.  Only DOM elements can take event handlers.  You should try passing it as a prop and having the `onClick` on the button itself.  See if this works:

```js
// In <App />
<InfoButton bttonClick={ this.alteringPeopleClicked } buttonText={'people'}/>

//In <InfoButton />
const InfoButton=(props)=>{
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <button onClick={props.buttonClick}>{props.buttonText}</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```